# not able to push a Rails App to Heroku using Git Bash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Puzzled. Please see below

```
$ git push heroku master
Could not create directory '/c/Users/Dipak/Git/.ssh'.
The authenticity of host 'heroku.com (50.19.85.156)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1f:c8:60:ad.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/c/Users/Dipak/Git/.ssh/known_hosts).
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Any ideas how to go about fixing the problem?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you have not uploaded your public key to Heroku, please try the following before pushing:

```
heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Note that `id_rsa.pub` is your public key, in your machine it might be named differently.

Comment: Looks like you also don't have permission to write to '/c/Users/Dipak/Git/.ssh'. Also, try running with the `--verbose` flag to get more output from git: `git push --verbose heroku master`

Comment: Thanks .. I corrected that ..however I am still not able to 'push' a Rails Folder (\iQvoc-1) to Heroku, pls see the steps below I did,